# How do I implement a batch task in redux-saga with limited concurrency and sane cancellation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to implement image uploads via redux-saga. The features I need to include are:

- Concurrent uploads limit. This is achieved by using a `channel` as [described in saga docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels.html)
- The action I listen to, `START_UPLOADS` in the code below, contains a (possible quite long) array of files which are published to the channel separately.
- I need to be able to cancel all current uploads via another action, `CANCEL_ACTION`, including those that arrived in any START_UPLOADS but weren't published to the channel yet, as well as those currently being processed in any of the `uploadImage` workers.

The code I arrived at is as follows. My problem with it is that the `cancelAll` handler is being executed AFTER the `finally` block that restarts the saga and the overall fact that I seem to need to restart everything. It looks clunky and error prone. Can you give any advice on whether this is how Sagas are meant to be used?

```
function* uploadImage(file) {
  const config = yield getConfig();
  const getRequest = new SagaRequest();
  console.log("Making async request here.");
}

function* consumeImages(uploadRequestsChannel) {
  while (true) {
    const fileAdded = yield take(uploadRequestsChannel);
    // process the request
    yield* uploadImage(fileAdded);
  }
}

function* uploadImagesSaga() {
  const CONCURRENT_UPLOADS = 10;
  const uploadRequestsChannel = yield call(channel);
  let workers = [];
  function* scheduleWorkers() {
    workers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < CONCURRENT_UPLOADS; i++) {
      const worker = yield fork(consumeImages, uploadRequestsChannel);
      workers.push(worker);
    }
  }

  let listener;
  yield* scheduleWorkers();

  function* cancelAll() {
    // cancel producer and consumers, flush channel
    yield cancel(listener);
    for (const worker of workers) {
      yield cancel(worker);
    }
    yield flush(uploadRequestsChannel);
  }

  function* putToChannel(chan, task) {
    return yield put(chan, task);
  }

  function* listenToUploads() {
    try {
      while (true) {
        const { filesAdded } = yield take(START_UPLOADS);
        for (const fileAdded of filesAdded) {
          yield fork(putToChannel, uploadRequestsChannel, fileAdded);
        }
      }
    } finally {
      // if cancelled, restart consumers and producer
      yield* scheduleWorkers();
      listener = yield fork(listenToUploads);
    }
  }

  listener = yield fork(listenToUploads);

  while (true) {
    yield take(CANCEL_ACTION);
    yield call(cancelAll);
  }
}

export default uploadImagesSaga;
```

EDIT: distilled into a sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cancellable-counter-example-qomw6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like using `race` for cancellation - the resolved value of the race is an object with one key and value (of the "winning" task). [redux-saga race() docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#raceeffects)

```
const result = yield race({
  cancel: take(CANCEL_ACTION),
  listener: call(listenToUploads), // use blocking `call`, not fork
});

if (result.cancel) {
  yield call(cancelAll)
}
```

^ This could be wrapped in a `while (true)` loop, so you should be able to consolidate the duplicated fork()s from the original example. If workers need to be re-scheduled, you could consider handling that inside `cancelAll`.

I prefer letting the outer-task handle restarts, rather than calling tasks from their own `finally` blocks.

Edit: refactored example sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/cancellable-counter-example-j5vxr

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I distilled the problem into a sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cancellable-counter-example-qomw6
My main problem is currently the fact that cancelling the workers still results in the dummy promise being finished successfully. Shouldn't `cancel()` prevent that?

Comment: One of my favorite parts of async tasks is that it provides an alternative to manual state management. So, to me, the array of workers was ripe for refactoring.

In this example, I mixed things up a bit: https://codesandbox.io/s/cancellable-counter-example-j5vxr --- the workers handle their own cancellations, so they don't need to be killed / reinitialized. We fork a cleanup task that clears the channel on each `CANCEL`, and then the saga just listens for the batch upload events. Hope it helps!

Comment: This is beyond excellent! Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed in this question.